# Get offset for specific timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone

**TLDR: I need the zone offset of "Europe/Berlin" on a specific day in IE, without using libraries or APIs. The only thing I can use is [this timezone polyfill](https://github.com/formatjs/date-time-format-timezone).**

I'm using an API that's returning a date, like this:

```json
{ date: "2021-01-01T12:00:00Z" }
```

This data is actually incorrect. The time given is actually the local time of "Europe/Berlin", the zulu time information is wrong. Sadly, the API can't be fixed at this moment, so I have to work around that.

I now want to use this date and compare it to the browser/system time. To do that, my approach would be to set the correct time zone on the API date, like this:

```js
const TZ_BERLIN = "+02:00";
const apiDate = "2021-01-01T12:00:00Z";

// Cut off the "Z", add the proper time zone
const correctDate = apiDate.substr(0, apiDate.length - 1) + TZ_BERLIN;
```

Then I can directly compare the dates. So I have to figure out the time zone offset of Berlin on this specific day (since it can change due to daylight saving time).

A few restrictions which make this issue even more difficult: I can't use any libraries or external APIs (a requirement which makes sense in this app, but I can't go into more detail here), and it has to run in all modern browsers, and IE.

I was able to include a [timezone polyfill](https://github.com/formatjs/date-time-format-timezone) for IE, so DateTimeFormat supports "Europe/Berlin".

I don't really know where to go from here. I can somehow get the timezone in Chrome using this:

```js
new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], { timezone: "Europe/Berlin", timeZoneName: "short" })
    .format(new Date("2021-01-01"));
// "1/1/2021, GMT+1"
```

Using the same command in IE, it prints `"‎01‎.‎01‎.‎2021"`. For the `timeZoneName` parameter, IE also only supports `short` and `long` - so i can't use eg. `shortOffset`.

Is there any way to get the offset in IE this way?

Comment: You've said you have to support IE (which is unfortunate, as it's obsolete, but lots of people do still have to support it). What version(s) do you need to support? IE8, 9, 10, and 11 are all different.

Comment: I stated this one explicitly, because I got it audited and approved internally, so I can use the polyfill. That's the only thing I can use right now. Also, IE 11 should be fine.

Comment: The problem is that it's not formatting you need, it's parsing, right? You need to know whether the date/times you're parsing (for instance `"2021-01-01T12:00:00Z"` but ignoring the `Z`) are during DST or not. `DateTimeFormat` is (as the name implies) for *formatting*, not *parsing*. I'd grab [the latest timezone data from IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) and extract just the `Europe/Berlin` data, which you should be able to format into an array of years which will only be a little over 100 in length (since DST was only supported there in 1918). Then parse the string and...

Comment: ...use the year, month, day, and time to figure out whether you need to apply the non-DST offset or the DST offset. Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's actually something I haven't thought about. This might actually work, I will try it! Thanks!